# I don't want other users to commit the files or delete the files in SVN that are created by me. but user should be able to read that particular file

Tags: svn

We are using the svn for centralized version control. We use to commit the file and takes the updates from the same.

But I have some files that should not be updated or delete by anyone who has a rights to access the svn accept me.

But other users are allowed to read those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@brendon one way of doing this is to get lock on particular file.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jaypal sodha its working fine for me.